# Discord JS : How can ı send message when create channel by bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Creating channel np , permissions ok , but how can ı send message when create channel but send message in created message? Here is my code;

I need to make send message when my bot create channel in created channel.

```
var kayitFormu = new Map();


bot.on('message', message => {
  if(message.author.bot) return;
  if(message.content.toLowerCase() === '!kayıt' && message.channel.id === 
  '701096677238374401')  

    if(kayitFormu.has(message.author.id)) {
      message.author.send("`Açık olan bir formun var!`/ **RAPIXEL APP**");
    } else {let guild = message.guild;


    guild.channels.create(`${message.author.username}-kayıtodası`, {



      type: 'text',
      topic: `!kapat yazarak form doldurmayı kapatabilirsin. `,
      message: 'denemee',
      permissionOverwrites: [
        {
          id: message.guild.id,
          deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],

        },
        {
          id: message.author.id,
          allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
        },
        {
          id: '701098731440832542',
          allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
        },
      ],
    }).then(ch => {
      channel => channel.send("Hello!");
      console.log("Kayıt formu olan " + ch.name + " oluşturuldu." );
      kayitFormu.set(message.author.id, ch.id)
      //channel => channel.send("Hello!");
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use `guild.channels.create()` you can use `.then()` to send a message to that specific channel without having to fetch/get it again.

```js
guild.channels.create(`${message.author.username}-kayıtodası`, {
      type: 'text',
      topic: `!kapat yazarak form doldurmayı kapatabilirsin. `,
      message: 'denemee',
}).then(channel => channel.send("Hello!"))
```

Comment: Okey, but how can ı send embed ?

Comment: you never mentioned an embed, and saying "didn't work" doesn't tell me what's wrong, please detail your issue/error

Comment: look my answer @Syntle

Comment: that does not tell me what's not working, could you please detail the issue/error you're having?

Comment: If my answer has solved your issue then please accept it to let others know what worked

Comment: this answer is correct and for @DefendeR saying of embed you just make a embed variable and instead of the string Hello type that embed variable name