# I need a code that sends a message every time a channel is created

Tags: discord, discord.js

I want my bot to send the message "first" every time a channel is created

the closest I could get was at [Discord JS : How can ı send message when create channel by bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61416120/discord-js-how-can-%C4%B1-send-message-when-create-channel-by-bot) but I don't want to that he sends the message only on channels he created himself, but on channels created by anyone

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`channelCreate`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-channelCreate) event.

Here's a simple example for you:

```js
client.on("channelCreate", async (channel) => {
  const channelName = channel.name;
  console.log(`New channel created: ${channelName}`);
});
```